# Demonstration of performance benefit of indexing a SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, sqlfiddle

I've always heard that "proper" indexing of one's SQL tables is key for performance. I've never seen a real-world example of this and would like to make one using [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) but not sure on the SQL syntax to do so.

Let's say I have 3 tables: 1) `Users` 2) `Comments` 3) `Items`.
Let's also say that each item can be commented on by any user. So to get item=3's comments here's what the SQL `SELECT` would look like:

```
SELECT * from comments join users on comments.commenter_id=users.user_id 
WHERE comments.item_id=3
```

I've heard that generally speaking if the number of rows gets large, i.e., many thousands/millions, one should put indices on the `WHERE` and the `JOIN`ed column. So in this case, `comments.item_id`, `comments.commenter_id`, and `users.user_id`.

I'd like to make a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to compare having these tables indexed vs. not using many thousands, millions rows for each table. Might someone help with generating this SQLFiddle?

Comment: Well, I think SQL fiddle is not the best tool for this. Get a MySQL instance, or a complete virtual appliance with MySQL, and do it on that. By the way, generating test data is not an easy thing to do. Best would be to get a copy of a real-life DB from somewhere and use that - but it is not the easiest thing to come by if you don't already have one at hand...

Comment: SQL Fiddle will limit you to about 8k of data, I think. You can get free versions of practically every dbms nowadays. Install your favorite, and use your favorite scripting language to generate data. (I like to learn a new language a couple of times a year, and things like this are a great excuse.)

Comment: @timpeterson . . . I think if you look over the questions asked on StackOverflow, you'll find many examples where indexing fixes problems (and a handful where it makes things worse).  You should study a bit about how databases work.  The performance improvements from indexing are pretty obvious from first principles.

Comment: Have a look at [Use The Index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm the owner of SQL Fiddle. It definitely is not the place for generating huge databases for performance testing. There are too many other variables that you don't (but should, in real life) have control over, such as memory, hdd configuration, etc.... Also, as a shared environment, there are other people using it which could also impact your tests. That being said, you can still build a small db in sqlfiddle and then view the execution plans for queries with and without indexes. These will be consistent regardless of other environmental factors, and will be a good source for learning optimization.

Comment: rocks.  As he says puleeeeze don't try to do benchmarking work on sqlfiddle.

Comment: hi @jake, sorry i didn't mean to cause a problem by suggesting we use SQLFiddle. My intention was simply to ask question whose answer could be easily accessible to others.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few different ways to index a table and you might choose to index multiple tables differently depending on what your most used SELECT statements are.  The 2 fundamental types of indexes are called clustered and non-clustered.

Clustered indexes store all of the information on the index itself rather than storing a list of references that the database can pull from and then use to find the actual data.  The easiest way to visualize this is to think of the index and the table itself as separate objects.  In a clustered index, if the column you indexed is used as a criterion (in the WHERE clause) then the information the query pulls will be pulled directly from the index and not the table.

On the other hand, non-clustered indexes is more like a reference table.  It tells the query where the actual information it is requesting is stored at on the table object itself.  So in essence, there is an extra step involved of actually retrieving the data from the table itself when you use non-clustered indexes.

Clustered indexes store data physically on the hard disk in a sequential order, and as a result of that, you can only have one clustered index on a table (since we can only store a table in one 'physical' way on a disk drive).  Clustered indexes also need to be unique (although this may not be the case to the naked eye, it is always the case to the database itself).  Because of this, most clustered indexes are put on the primary key (since most primary keys are unique).

Unlike clustered indexes, you can have as many non-clustered indexes are you want on a table since after all, they are just reference tables for the actual table itself.  Since we have an essentially unlimited number of options for non-clustered indexes, users like to put as many of these as needed on columns that are commonly used in the WHERE clause of a SELECT statement.

But like all things, excess is not always good.  The more indexes you put on a table, the more 'overhead' there is on that table.  Indexes might speed up your query runs, but excessive overhead will also slow them down.  The key is to find a balance between too many indexes and not enough indexes for your particular situation.

As far as a good place to test the performance of your queries with or without indexes, I would recommend using SQL Server.  There's a function in SQL Server Management Studio called 'Execution Plan' which tells you the cost and time to run of a query.